# Powershell Convert DateTime to dd mon yyyy

Tags: powershell

I want to convert a date to this format "dd Mon yyyy".

I have this code which works:

```
$date = [DateTime]::Parse("21/11/2014")
$dateFormatted = $date.GetDateTimeFormats()[12]
#$dateFormatted displays 21 November 2014
```

Is there a way to convert it using something like this?:

```
$dateFormatted = $date.ToString("dd Mon yyyy")
```

At the moment this returns "21 11on 2014"

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out:

```
$dateFormatted = $date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
```